Is it possible to modify the Source Control section in VSCode?
Is it possible to modify the Source Control section in VSCode? I tried to add an intelligent commit generation icon to the Source Control section, but I couldn't find any relevant information in the documentation.
Maybe someone knew it

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Jira Commit Message adds a Jira icon to the source control view.
I think that it's done by this code in package.json:
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "jira-commit-message.update-message",
        "title": "Update Commit Message",
        "icon": "assets/jira_icon.svg"
      }
    ],
    "menus": {
            "scm/title": [
                {
                    "command": "jira-commit-message.update-message",
                    "group": "navigation"
                }
            ]
        },


It's a good start adding an icon to Source Control, but there's an issue with multi-repos. The button can't determine which repository is currently selected.

@Sma1lboy. Do you want to show or hide it depending on what repository is currently selected or is it the command run by the button that should operate on the selected repository?

I want the command to run on the selected repository. I built an auto-generate commit function, and it works perfectly on a single repository. However, when I open a multi-repository project, there is no API in VSCode to determine which repository you have selected at the moment. For example, consider generating a Jira commit message, example.

Have you checked the git extension API?
